# faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(imgGray,1.3,5)

Tags: python, opencv

```
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(imgGray,1.3,5)
```

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-6sxsq0tp\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem experienced by many. Solve it by adding the cv2 data path at the initialization stage.

## Creating face_cascade and eye_cascade objects

This is your face detection and eye detection initialization

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Change them to the following format

```
face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades +"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_eye.xml")
```